# Return the most recent record according to a snapshot date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 4 columns (snapshotDate, systemID, companyID, State)
the table can have different snapshots for each system for the same companyID in the same state.

I want to write a query to return the most recent record for each record in the month for each system with in the same companyID in and same state.

For example:

```
snapshotDate    systemID    companyID   State
12/31/2017           A        2         FL
12/30/2017           A        2         FL
12/29/2017           A        2         FL
03/25/2018           B        5         WA
03/20/2018           B        5         WA
```

In this case I want the result to be as follows:

```
snapshotDate    systemID    companyID   State
12/31/2017           A        2         FL 
03/25/2018           B        5         WA
```

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window function`  with *top(1) with ties*

```
select top(1) with ties systemID, *
from table t
order by row_number() over (partition by systemID order by snapshotDate desc)
```

You could also use `subquery` instead

```
select * from table t
where snapshotDate = (select max(snapshotDate) from table where systemID = t.systemID)
```

But, as per your sample data you could do that via `group by` clause

```
select max(snapshotDate) snapshotDate, systemID, companyID, State
from table t
group by systemID, companyID, State
```

Comment: Talk about overkill :) but an interesting solution nonetheless! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this query

```
select max(snapshotDate) snapshotDate ,systemID, companyID, State 
from tablename 
group by systemID, companyID, State;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `WINDOW FUNCTION Row_Number()`.

**TRY THIS:**

```
SELECT snapshotDate,systemID,companyID,State 
FROM(
    SELECT snapshotDate,systemID,companyID,State
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY systemID ORDER BY snapshotDate DESC)RN  
    FROM Your_Table
    )D
WHERE D.RN = 1
```

Comment: For such cases you can place the `ROW_NUMBER()` directly into the `ORDER BY` clause and use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. No sub-select needed...

Comment: @Shnugo, Thank you for the suggestion. I'll keep it in the future.